# Merging Many to Many Results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm using the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM prefix_site_tmplvars
LEFT JOIN prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues 
ON prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid = prefix_site_tmplvars.id
LEFT JOIN prefix_site_content
ON prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid = prefix_site_content.id
WHERE prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value = "chocolate"
```

This is what I get back:

```
[id] => 2  
[name] => flavor  
[value] => chocolate

[id] => 2 
[name] => type 
[value] => cookie
```

This is the result I'd like to get:

```
[id] => 2
[flavor] => chocolate
[type] => cookie
```

Is there a way to combine my results so I don't have a bunch of rows referring to the same ID? If now, how should I handle this?

I'm using Modx and this is working with the Template Variable tables: http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Template_Variable_Database_Tables

Comment: It might help if you explain your table schema in the question.

Comment: you need to explain yourself better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use case statements:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    MAX( CASE WHEN name = 'flavor' THEN value ELSE NULL END ) AS flavor,
    MAX( CASE WHEN name = 'type' THEN value ELSE NULL END ) AS type
FROM prefix_site_tmplvars
    LEFT JOIN prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues 
    ON prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid = prefix_site_tmplvars.id
    LEFT JOIN prefix_site_content
    ON prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid = prefix_site_content.id
WHERE prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value = "chocolate"
GROUP BY id
```

Of course, this approach only works if you know ahead of time what keys you want to select; but it seems like in this case you do know (flavor + type).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you might have

```
{ "id": 2, "flavor": "chocolate", "type": "cookie" }
```

and another row with

```
{ "id": 3, "flavor": "vanilla", "calories": "375" }
```

...I don't think there's an easy way to solve the problem in MySQL; you'd need to decide what keys to look for.

On the other hand you can collapse the rows in PHP:

```
while($tuple = ...fetch tuple from mysql cursor...)
{
    list ($id, $name, $value) = $tuple;
    if (!isset($objs[$id]))
    {
        // You might want to add also "'id' => $id" to the array definition
        $objs[$id]= array ($name => $value);
    }
    else
    {
        $obj = $objs[$id];
        $obj[$name] = $value;
        $objs[$id] = $obj;
    }
}
```

Now $objs contains the desired data; you still need to get it back into Modx, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a group by:

```
SELECT id,
       max(case when name = 'flavor' then value end) as flavor,
       max(case when name = 'type' then value end) as type
FROM prefix_site_tmplvars LEFT JOIN
     prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues
     ON prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid = prefix_site_tmplvars.id LEFT JOIN
        prefix_site_content ON prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.contentid = prefix_site_content.id
WHERE prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value = "chocolate" 
group by id
```